# Error when creating a simple custom dynamic tokenizer in Python

Tags: python, tokenize, python-re

I am trying to create a dynamic tokenizer, but it does not work as intended.

Below is my code:

```
import re

def tokenize(sent):

  splitter = re.findall("\W",sent)
  splitter = list(set(splitter))

  for i in sent:
    if i in splitter:
      sent.replace(i, "<SPLIT>"+i+"<SPLIT>")

  sent.split('<SPLIT>')
  return sent


sent = "Who's kid are you? my ph. is +1-6466461022.Bye!"

tokens = tokenize(sent)

print(tokens)
```

This does not work!

I expected it to return the below list:

```
["Who", "'s", "kid", "are", "you","?", "my" ,"ph",".", "is", "+","1","-",6466461022,".","Bye","!"]
```

Comment: You’re modifying `sent` while iterating over it - that’s doomed, you should copy from sent into a different variable for the result.

Comment: I copied 'sent' into another variable 'temp'. Then replaced all occurrences of 'sent' inside the function except the one in line "for i in sent:". Still does not work.

Comment: *replace* and *split* do not modify the string *in situ*. That's your fundamental mistake.

Comment: The special `'` role cannot be really coded easily with re or just using split approach like yours. The solution below "glues" `'` to the subsequent token if it is enclosed with letters. Else, it is a separate token.

Comment: I see what you mean about the apostrophe combined with the word. But I still do not understand as to why the code never splits anything when <SPLIT> is encountered - result is just a string with 0 splits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty trivial if it weren't for the special treatment of the `'`. I'm assuming you're doing NLP, so you want to take into account which "side" the `'` belongs to. For instance, `"tryin'"` should not be split and neither should `"'tis"` (it is).

```
import re


def tokenize(sent):
    split_pattern = rf"(\w+')(?:\W+|$)|('\w+)|(?:\s+)|(\W)"
    return [word for word in re.split(split_pattern, sent) if word]

sent = (
    "Who's kid are you? my ph. is +1-6466461022.Bye!",
    "Tryin' to show how the single quote can belong to either side",
    "'tis but a regex thing + don't forget EOL testin'",
    "You've got to love regex"
)

for item in sent:
    print(tokenize(item))
```

The python `re` lib evaluates patterns containing `|` from left to right and it is non-greedy, meaning it stops as soon as a match is found, even though it's not the longest match.

Furthermore, a feature of the `re.split()` function is that you can use match groups to retain the patterns/matches you're splitting at (otherwise the string is split and the matches where the splits happen are dropped).

Pattern breakdown:

1. `(\w+')(?:\W+|$)` - words followed by a `'` with no word characters immediately following it. E.g., `"tryin'"`, `"testin'"`. Don't capture the non-word characters.
2. ('\w+) - `'` followed by at least one word character. Will match `"'t"` and `"'ve"` in `"don't"` and `"they've"`, respectively.
3. (?:\s+) - split on any whitespace, but discard the whitespace itself
4. (\W) - split on all non-word characters (no need to bother finding the subset that's present in the string itself)

Comment: You're right, I was working on creating a custom tokenizer and replace the slang sentences to a more formal one. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
[x for x in re.split(r"([^'\w\s]|'(?![^\W\d_])|(?<![^\W\d_])')|(?='(?<=[^\W\d_]')(?=[^\W\d_]))|\s+", sent) if x]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HOvdx2/4). The pattern matches

- `(` - Group 1 (as these texts are captured into a group these matches appear in the resulting list):

  - `[^'\w\s]` - any char other than `'`, word and whitespace char
  - `|` - or
  - `'(?![^\W\d_])` - a `'` not immediately followed with a letter (`[^\W\d_]` matches any Unicode letter)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<![^\W\d_])'` - a `'` not immediately preceded with a letter
- `)` - end of the group
- `|` - or
- `(?='(?<=[^\W\d_]')(?=[^\W\d_]))` - a location right before a `'` char that is enclosed with letters
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Vq85M9):

```py
import re

sents = ["Who's kid are you? my ph. is +1-6466461022.Bye!", "Who's kid are you? my ph. is +1-6466461022.'Bye!'"]
for sent in sents:
    print( [x for x in re.split(r"([^'\w\s]|'(?![^\W\d_])|(?<![^\W\d_])')|(?='(?<=[^\W\d_]')(?=[^\W\d_]))|\s+", sent) if x] )

# => ['Who', "'s", 'kid', 'are', 'you', '?', 'my', 'ph', '.', 'is', '+', '1', '-', '6466461022', '.', 'Bye', '!']
# => ['Who', "'s", 'kid', 'are', 'you', '?', 'my', 'ph', '.', 'is', '+', '1', '-', '6466461022', '.', "'", 'Bye', '!', "'"]
```

Comment: This is spot on. Full on with regex !